# Autoloaded php code not updating after edits inside of Lando environment

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, lando

The crux of the issue is that I **edit a code file and the change does not take effect** until after I rebuild my entire environment. Weird thing is that I haven't been having this issue for months of development so far. I just decided to dust off this project and work on it this week and **all of a sudden** editing files no longer works (without a rebuild).

I don't even know where to begin to try and tackle this. Any advise helps, especially from people who have experience with Lando and Docker. Alright, so because I don't have any idea what's causing this, I'll just try and explain my whole set up and go from there:

I'm using Lando to run a container which is running PHP 7.3. When I SSH into the running container and execute my script `php worker.php` my script runs no problems. Then if I edit it, say to add a var_dump('hello world!'), I get the expected output. However, if I edit an autoloaded class file, say MyClass.php, and add a var_dump there, nothing happens. In fact I have to completely rebuild the environment with `lando rebuild` in order to get the var_dump to show up. Weird right?

Ok so here are some things I've tried:

- I've tried restarting Docker.
- I've tried restarting my computer.
- I've tried `lando destroy` and `lando rebuild` to start fresh.
- I've tried SSHing into the container and running `cat mylib/MyClass.php` and I see the added var_dump statement!! However when I run `php worker.php` the var_dump added to MyClass isn't there. How can it be present in the filesystem, yet absent during execution? This is really throwing me for a loop.
- I've tried renaming MyClass.php to MyClass2.php and this fixes the issue ONCE. I.e. after it updates I then need to rename it again and again each time there is a change. This obviously isn't a real solution, but it's food for thought.
- I've tried manually loading classes using `include_once`. This works perfectly, edits take effect as soon as they happen. The problem is that I don't want to manually include all my files, I want to use the composer autoloader. I've been using it for a long time, I'd prefer to just fix whatever has suddenly gone wrong with it.

Ok lastly, some theories of mine:

- Something is obviously caching stuff but I have no idea what. I thought maybe it was something to do with the PHP Opcode caching, but I, to my knowledge, don't have php opcode caching enabled.
- Another theory is that maybe the filesystem mount isn't working. It is working, however, because when I edit worker.php the changes are instantly there each time. This would not be happening if there was no filesystem mount.
- One more theory is that either Docker is caching something somehow (I have no idea how), or maybe Lando is? I don't know Lando inside and out. Maybe it has some sort of caching scheme I'm not aware of.
- Last theory is that somehow autoloaded classes are cached by PHP itself or my composer or something like that. I also don't know how this is possible, but I'm not an expert on the inner workings of composer or php so if there is a code cache involved here somewhere I'm not aware of it.

So some things I know people might ask for:
Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
       git \
       zip \
       unzip \
       libzip-dev \
       libxml2-dev \
       libssl-dev \
       libc-client-dev \
       libkrb5-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && CFLAGS="-I/usr/src/php" docker-php-ext-install zip mysqli pdo pdo_mysql xmlreader imap

RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Bake composer dependencies into the image for production
WORKDIR /app

COPY composer.json ./
COPY composer.lock ./

RUN export COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 && \
    composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev

COPY . ./

RUN export COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 && \
    composer dump-autoload --optimize && \
    composer run-script post-install-cmd

COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data ./ && \
    a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80
```

.lando.yml

```
name: mysite
env_file:
  - .env
proxy:
  appserver:
    - mysite.lndo.site
  database:
    - db.mysite.lndo.site
services:
  appserver:
    type: compose
    services:
      build: .
      command: apache2-foreground
  database:
    type: mysql
    portforward: 3306
    creds:
      ---super secret---
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "MySite/MySite",
    "description": "Would work great if not for caching issues. :(",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-imap": "*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.6.2",
        "doctrine/migrations": "^2.0",
        "zbateson/mail-mime-parser": "^1.1",
        "rct567/dom-query": "^0.7.0",
        "sabre/xml": "^2.1",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MySite\\": "./lib"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update:
I've found that by deleting `vendor/symfony/console` and then running `composer install` it seems to clear the cache. I wish I could figure it out from here, but the answer still eludes me. What does symfony console have to do with autoload caching code?? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, but it took me all day. I hope someone stumbles across this and it saves you time. Here is what I had to do, it was so easy:

Just put the following code into your composer.json file and run `composer install`!

```
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
```

I don't know WHY this works though. I kind of would assume that enabling the optimizer would CAUSE caching, but instead it seems to disable it. I honestly have no idea why this works. If someone else can explain this better than me, then I'd vote for your answer over mine.